# Hudson: how to disable build delete confirmation?

Tags: hudson

I am sending a simple GET request via the API

```
http://myhudson/job/jobname/lastBuild/delete
```

however, hudson seems  to require delete confirmation button to be pressed. How can I disable this ?

Comment: What version of hudson you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would (not tested)

```
http://myhudson/job/jobname/lastBuild/doDelete
```

works better?